# Entity Framework stored procedure Insert custom sequential number

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

Please bear with me is a long explanation.

I have a set up a table in EF4 using mapped stores procedure for inserting data.

Example :

```
    id | location | type
    1  |     10   |  15
    5  |     10   |  16
```

What the SP does is to check in another table the next id that corresponds by location and type.

So in this example the next id would be

- 2 for location 10 and type 15
- 6 for location 10 type 16

This works by mapping a result column in EF.

It works ok except when two different keys have the same sequential number example:

```
    id | location | type
    1  |     10   |  11
    1  |     10   |  10
```

Edit: this error occurs when I am creating both new rows at the same time.

The next value for both of them is 2, the data is saved to the database but the application fails with this message:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred 
>   while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an 
>   inconsistent state.
>   Inner exception message:
>   AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another
>   object in the ObjectStateManager.
>   Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Any advice?

Edit 
Stored procedure example

> declare @nextNumber int
>
> SELECT @nextNumber = value + 1  FROM SEQUENTIAL_TABLE WHERE location = @location and type=@type
>
> INSERT INTO TABLE (location, type, id ,......) VALUES (@location, @type,@nextnumber, .......)
>
> UPDATE SEQUENTIAL_TABLE SET value = @nextNumber WHERE location = @location and type=@type
>
> SELECT @nextNumber as [NextNumber]

Comment: Try assigning bogus negative keys to new entities. Like -1, -2 so EF could separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the design; you could modify your table so that ID is not a primary key, but rather use the set of ID/Location/Type as a composite key.

Comment: hi
that's how it is set up, ID/Location/type all-together are the key

Comment: Is ID also inadvertently set in the database as a primary key by itself?

Comment: No, the only PK is the composite of the 3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're mis-using the id column to not just mean "auto-incrementing int".

Comment: Can you explain your comment please? I added an example of the sp i am using.

Comment: Typically one has a column that is purely a unique identifier for a row.  (Sadly the term "unique identifier is overloaded, and typically means "Guid".  I'm not using that definition, rather just "unique".)  Usually this column is named <tablename>Id or just Id.  It appears in your use-case, the Id column represents "sequence of location / type", and there is no "unique" column.

Answer (score 0):

The "bogus negative numbers" is a great trick, and worked very nicely in the DataSet / TableAdapter days.  If that doesn't work, perhaps this is a race condition, and you need to place the details in a transaction such that no other threads / rows can get the next id until you're done incrementing and inserting yours.